# Conflicting CSS classes on Kendo widgets

Tags: css, kendo-ui

I am trying to scope two css classes against two different Kendo widgets -

1) a tabstrip widget in my sidebar.html (trying to set a black background)

2) a grid in the main content html page (trying to set a silver background)

The kendo-tab-strip Angular directive has my custom class 'tabsCustom' -

```
<div class="sidebar-inner">     <!-- KENDO TABS WITH INCLUDE FILES -->
  <div id="tabs" class="tabsCustom"
    kendo-tab-strip     
    k-content-urls="['../app/include/treeview-include.html', '../app/include/gadgets-include.html']">
    <ul>
    <li class="k-state-active">Reports</li>
    <li>Gadgets</li>
    </ul>              
  </div>
```

whereas the grid widget contains its own class 'gridCustom' -

```
<div id="wizard4" class="reportwizardDimen gridCustom row-fluid">   
<h3>Choose a Dimension grouping</h3>  
<span id="userDimenGrid" kendo-grid="vm.userDimenGrid" 
      k-data-source="vm.userDimenGridDS"
      k-options="vm.userDimenGridOptions" 
      k-rebind="vm.userDimenGridOptions" />
```

However, class '**gridCustom**' appears to be overriding the '**tabsCustom**' class as demonstrated in this screen shot (i.e.the SILVER background color overrides):

[image: css settings]

Do I need further selectors or a higher specificity somewhere ?

thanks in advance,

Bob

Comment: Try forcing the styles using `!important` in your CSS definition

Comment: I tried `background-color: black !important;` in my css, but whichever css class I add it to this takes precedence (which I know is the point). However, one overrides the other - so I'm totally missing something.

Comment: In other words, I still get either BLACK or SILVER on the tabstrip and grid. I can't seem to isolate those colors.

Comment: Could you publish in JSFiddle/JSBin or a functional snippet here reproducing the question? The idea is forcing whichever you need *but* narrowing it to apply to only the desired elements using their `id` o unique class selector.